# Tarantool's replication from Oracle

Tags: oracle, caching, replication, tarantool

I didn't find article or doc with example of Tarantool's replication from Oracle.
Does anybody have example or instruction for this cool feature?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tarantool has open-source connectors for PostgreSQL, MySQL and Memcached (as part of its Community edition). Oracle replication specifically is part of  Tarantool Enterprise, which comes with support (DB2 and SQL Server are also Enterprise). If you are interested, there is a demo request form [here](https://tarantool.io/live-demo).

Comment: Thank you for link.

Comment: Sure, no problem.